# Why comments don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I create user->posts->comments associations, but comments don't work right.When I commented post, comment save to data base, column user_id was recorded (ok), but column post_id is empty.

There is partial _post_list.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= post.title %></td>
      <td><%= post.content %></td>
      <%= render 'shared/comment' %>
      <%= post.user.name %>
      </tr></br></br>
      <% end %>
```

There is partial _comment.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :body %><br><br>
<%= f.submit "commented" %>
<% end %>
```

controller comments_controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @comment = Comment.new
    end

    def create
        @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
        if @comment.save
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            render 'static_pages/home'
        end
    end

     private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

**UPD** there is server log

```
Started POST "/posts/6/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-16 23:28:26 +0300
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZvyHKxSdH0a1rf79yaWmo9N/pD9/YhSQ9Ek8bdMLhOI=", "comment"=>{"body"=>"stackoverflow"}, "commit"=>"commented", "post_id"=>"6"}
  User Load (4.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'b52623cb00671708536fce96c310b5d365128880' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("body", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["body", "stackoverflow"], ["created_at", "2014-11-16 20:28:26.544500"], ["updated_at", "2014-11-16 20:28:26.544500"], ["user_id", 5]]
   (131.7ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 152ms (ActiveRecord: 137.4ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-16 23:28:26 +0300
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'b52623cb00671708536fce96c310b5d365128880' LIMIT 1
  Rendered shared/_post_form.html.erb (2.4ms)
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"   ORDER BY created_at DESC
  Rendered shared/_comment.html.erb (1.8ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Rendered shared/_comment.html.erb (2.8ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered shared/_comment.html.erb (4.0ms)
  CACHE (3.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered shared/_comment.html.erb (1.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered shared/_comment.html.erb (2.9ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered shared/_post_list.html.erb (45.3ms)
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (52.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 364ms (Views: 347.0ms | ActiveRecord: 4.5ms)
```

controller static_pages_controller
    class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
        def index
        end

```
    def show
    end

    def home
    @post = current_user.posts.build 
    if signed_in?
    end
    @posts = Post.all
    @comment = current_user.comments.build
    end

end
```

view home.html.erb

```
<%= render 'shared/post_form' %>
<%= render 'shared/post_list' %>
```

How fix?
sorry for my bad English

Comment: Can you post your controller code? You aren't telling `@comment` which `@post` it belongs to. Once you post your controller, we can tell you what needs to be changed.

Comment: comments_controller or posts_controller?

Comment: comments, assuming that's where your create action is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looping through all of your posts and creating a comment form on the same page for each. You may want to set your comment routes up as nested resources by wrapping it within the post resource.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

Pass your @post object into the partial like so:

```
<%= render 'shared/comment', post: post %>
```

Then you should be able to create your comment form like so:

```
<%= form_for([post,@comment]) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :body %><br><br>
<%= f.submit "commented" %>
<% end %>
```

By including that `post`, you are telling the comment which post it belongs to. Don't forget to update your strong parameters in the controller if you are using them.

EDIT: Based on your update, you'll need to add `:post_id` to the permit at the bottom of our controller.

Comment: I edited view and controller, but error displayed No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments", :format=>nil, :post_id=>#<Post id: nil, title: nil, content: nil, user_id: 5, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>} missing required keys: [:post_id]

Comment: I updated my answer to include the `post` variable in the partial and remove the `@` from the form_for. We needed to pass that variable in since @post isn't there by default. I'm not sure why it was trying to hit comments#index, though. Did it show you that before or after you submitted the form?

Comment: I think the only thing you're missing now is the update to `comment_params` in your controller. Make it `params.require(:comment).permit(:post_id, :body)`.

Comment: but I added ':post_id', maybe problem due to the fact that all of this working in the 'static_pages' controller?I include methods in method 'home' static_pages controller.I updated question

Answer (score 1):

You are far from showing enough code to allow us to understand what can happen. But I feel strange that your form does not include somewhere a reference to `post.id` or whatever you name the identifier for post objects.

The controller will only be able to use :

- input fields of the form (here text of comment)
- session stored values (user id)

If the current post id is neither in form fields, not in session, the controller will not get id, it you cannot store it in database.